# Don't understand why this while loop isn't terminating

Tags: python, while-loop, terminate

I am trying to implement a simple fast_exponentiation algorithm based on repeated squaring. But somehow my while loop does not terminate, eventhough the conditional variable n seems to reach 0. Below is my code and the output it generates:

```
def fast_exponentiation(a, n):
    result = 1
    b = a
    while n > 0:
        print(n)
        if n%2 == 1:
            result = result*b
            n = n-1
        b = pow(b,b)
        n = int(n/2)
    print("Here")
    return result


print(fast_exponentiation(2,12))
```

The output is:

```
12
6
3
1
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: It's getting stuck in `pow()` with a huge number.  Trace `b`.

Comment: @cdrake: That's it now it is working!!!!

Comment: @cdarke How mundane. Not sorcery after all. =)

Comment: Why did this happen? Could you explain please?

Comment: Like I said, trace `b`.  Think what you expect the result of `pow(b, b)` to be on each iteration..

Comment: Ah, now I see it too. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @3nondatur try  to insert an else to your code. after n=n-1.